# Javascript refactor, it's possible to use map & filter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

This is the return in a function, I want to apply a 40% of discount in an array, just in case the product color is red. This is the return, it's working.
I would like to know a way to refactor it, also I would like to know if it's possible to chain filter function in this case, if is possible how it should be done?
Also if you can do it with better pure functions I would appreciate, I'm learning functional programming.

```
return cart.map( (x) => {
  if (x.color === "red") {
    x.price = x.price * 0.4;
  }
   return x;
 });
```

Thank you

Comment: if you don't mind using an external library, you could use lodash [chain](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#chain) method

Comment: What do you want to `filter`?

Comment: @Zoti no library

Comment: @Andy not filtering the array, but applying it to just the red color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implicitly return using ternary operator. You can't use `filter()` because it changes the length and your code doesn't need to changed length

```
return cart.map(x => x.color === "red" ? {...x, price:x.price * 0.4} : x)
```

Comment: Be aware though that this solution will replace the object in the resulting array when the color is red. So the element in the input array does not strictly equal the element in the output-array at the same index, anymore.

Comment: @Codekie This Q is tagged FP, so reference identity (of objects) doesn't matter.

Comment: @bob Just based on this code snippet, we can't tell if it matters nor not, regardless of the FP tag. Changes on the input or output-array may or may not reflect on the other array, based on the color. And that we can't tell only by this snippet. Also, if the callback is supposed to be a pure function, then the return value should be a new object in all cases as the input value must not be modified. As it is right now, it's inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, the object in the resulting array should be replaced. I'm trying to understand this solutions, looks great.
The {...x, price: x.price*0.4} means that I'm just modifying the price in that element?

Comment: @Bernardao `{...x, price: x.price*0.4}` means that a new object is created, `price` will receive a new value and all other properties of `x` will be collected (also see [rest syntax in destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring)) and assigned to the new object.

If a new object is supposed to be returned in any case, the else branch should return `{...x}`

Comment: @Codekie _if the callback is supposed to be a pure function, then the return value should be a new object_ - no. It only has to be a new object when its type has changed. Again, in FP you shouldn't rely on referential identity but on values.

Comment: @Codekie making a copy in the `else` branch is wasteful and misunderstood

Comment: @bob I get your point. But just because this piece of code is going to be FP, it doesn't mean that the code around it, will be. And judging by this code, immutable values are not used and thus referencial identity very likely matters. In that case it's better to be consistent. Either modify the objects in place are return a new copy. And that was my initial intent. Pointing out that it is inconsistent.

Comment: @Codekie I got your point too. Besides my previous comment was imprecise: A new object has to be created whenever the value has changed, not the underlying type.

Answer (score 5):

Current code is OK in general, if you want to reduce amount of if statements and reuse `isRed` filter and `discount` function, then you could change it to something similar to:

```
const cart = [{price: 3, color: 'red'}, {price: 3, color: 'blue'}];

const applyIf = (condition, fn) => {
    return x => condition(x) ? fn(x) : x;
}

const isRed = x => x.color === 'red';

const discount = x => ({ ...x, price: x.price * 0.4 });

cart.map(applyIf(isRed, discount))
```

Comment: Instead of `x => {return {...}}`, why not `x => ({...})`?

Comment: Thank you for that answer @udalmik it also helped me to understand better the pure functions. I voted Maheer answer, because it was what I was looking for, even if I couldn't ask it in the proper way